# Data bound to children is not updated with new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am adding an element and a child in an `enter()` selection in D3.js:

```
let data = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
selection.data( data ).append( 'g' )
    .attr( 'name', d => d )
    .append( 'text' )
    .text( d => d );
```

This creates some elements, as expected:

```
<g name="1"><text>1</text></g>
<g name="2"><text>2</text></g>
<g name="3"><text>3</text></g>
```

When loading new data, the `g` elements receive it, but the `text` elements are still bound to the previous data:

```
let data = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ];
selection.attr( 'name', d => d )
    .selectAll( 'text' )
    .text( d => `[${d}]` ); // <- Remains unchanged
```

Result – 1, 2, 3 should not be there anymore:

```
<g name="A"><text>1</text></g>
<g name="B"><text>2</text></g>
<g name="C"><text>3</text></g>
```

How do I use D3 correctly so that the `text` elements will receive the new data as well?

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/07nvax31/1/

Comment: can you add a fiddle ?

Comment: Use `.select("text")` instead of `.selectAll("text")` when updating.

Comment: @Dragon_Slayer done.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Could you add this as an answer?

Comment: Added answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When updating, you can simply use `.select("text")` instead of `.selectAll("text")` to make it work. The difference between the two is that `.select()` updates the data bound to the selected element with that of the parent element, whereas `.selectAll()` doesn't. As you have only one `text` element per `g`, `.select()` is enough here.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to separate the `<g>`s from the `<text>`s. Then you can rebind the data separately:

```
// Set up an SVG already in the document
var svg = d3.select('svg');

// Create the groups with data bound to them
var data = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var gs = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data( data ).enter()
    .append( 'g' )
    .attr( 'name', String);

// Add text as children to each group, with the data passed through
var text = gs.append( 'text' ).text(String);

// Update the data and attributes/text for each
data = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ];
gs.data( data ).attr( 'name', String )
text.data( data ).text( function(d){ return `[${d}]`; });
```

This gives me the following:

[image: screenshot of svg structure]

Note that I had to rework your code a bit to have a complete example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I would actually prefer not doing it this way because the data is not really coupled and might get out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

(This is just a sidenote, @LarsKotthoff answer in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428714/data-bound-to-children-is-not-updated-with-new-data#comment68108548_40428714) is the right one)

You can access the data of the parent node (in this case, the group element) using `this.parentNode-__data__`, keeping the `selectAll`.

For instance, this:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var data = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

var groups = svg.selectAll(".groups").data(data);
groups.enter().append('g')
    .attr('name', (d) => d )
    .append('text')
    .text((d)=> d );
```

Will give you:

```
<g name="1"><text>1</text></g>
<g name="2"><text>2</text></g>
<g name="3"><text>3</text></g>
```

But if you change the data and bind it again to the groups, you can use `this.parentNode.__data__` to get the data of the respective group inside its child (the text element).

Thus, this:

```
var data = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ];

groups.data(data).attr( 'name', (d) => d )
    .selectAll('text')
    .text(function(){ return this.parentNode.__data__});
```

Will now give you:

```
<g name="A"><text>A</text></g>
<g name="B"><text>B</text></g>
<g name="C"><text>C</text></g>
```

Please notice that, as the code is using `this`, we cannot use a fat arrow function here.

Check the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var data = [1, 2, 3];

var groups = svg.selectAll(".groups").data(data);
groups.enter().append('g')
    .attr('name', (d) => d)
    .append('text')
    .text((d) => d);

var firstSVG = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg.node());

var data = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

groups.data(data).attr('name', (d) => d).selectAll('text')
    .text(function() {
        return this.parentNode.__data__
    });

var secondSVG = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg.node());

console.log("First SVG:" + firstSVG)
console.log("Second SVG:" + secondSVG)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice answer with the demo code! I would give 2 upvotes if I could :) I did not know about `parentNode`, might come in handy in future.